# Create generic method to forward to index.html requestes which throws 404

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, routes, forwarding

I `Spring Boot` app combined with `Angular 4`. I created some routes but when I type into `url` some string like `localhost:8080/items` I get error `404 not found`. So that's why I created `forwarding` when it detected if it the `url` looks like `localhost:8080/items` it forwards to `index.html`. But what about a case when I have multiple possible `urls` to typed and I don't want to rewirte it again and again...?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/item", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/item", method = RequestMethod.POST)
.
.
.
and so on
```

I wanted to create something generic like:

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping({ "/**" })
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work at all. Or there is another way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The proper correction of this case is:

In `app.module` add

```
  { path: '**', component: ItemListComponent}
```

which indicated what should you do when something goes wrong and add a specific `java controller` :

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}
```